# Combining folder and files like in zip

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, attributes, zip

how would one go about combining folders and files into one object like zip files do?

Say you want to create an app that does the same as any compression tool. You choose a folder and it combines all the files in it and its subfolders to one object.

You would have to save the folder structure and each file information into some value. But where would you do that. In the finished objects attributes?

Some starting point on this would be great and very appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `tar` command line tool would do what you wish, and you can run any command line tool using the `NSTask` class, that would be the direction I'd point you in.

- [NSTask Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [tar(1) Mac OS X Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tar.1.html)

Answer (score 1):

Also below is the way to implement the same:-

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/bash"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c", @"tar -xzf yourFile",nil]];
NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",response);
```